# Can I force python-mode's (or syntastic's) error flags over the line number columns?

Tags: plugin-syntastic, signs

When syntastic or python-mode finds an error in my python file, they create a new column at the left-hand side of the window with flags at the lines where the errors are:

[image: Terminal window showing vim with python-mode syntax error flags and line numbers]

This new column not only causes buffer to shift (which I find disruptive), but also prevents my 80-column-width lines from fitting nicely in the window.

Is there a way to have these flags placed in the line number column?

For longer files, I understand these flags would probably replace overwrite the numbers in the lines they appear. I wouldn't have a problem with that.

Comment: "For longer files, I understand these flags would probably replace overwrite the numbers in the lines they appear. I wouldn't have a problem with that."

You could consider not showing the number column or at least making it thinner (`set numberwidth=2`). I know it doesn't solve your problem, but I figure it doesn't hurt to mention.

Comment: Make your window 2 columns wider and permanently enable signs? :)

Answer (score 5):

No, this unfortunately isn't possible. The *signs column* is separate, and always with a width of two cells. From `:help signs`:

> When signs are defined for a file, Vim will automatically add a column of two
>   characters to display them in.  When the last sign is unplaced the column
>   disappears again.

You could only configure Syntastic to not use signs at all (via `let g:syntastic_enable_signs = 0`, thanks @lcd047!).

Comment: Disabling signs in syntastic: `let g:syntastic_enable_signs = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by adding `set signcolumn=number` to your .vimrc.

Showing signs in the number column was added in [v8.1.1564](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/394c5d8870b15150fc91a4c058dc571fd5eaa97e).